# How can I set a DateTimePicker control to a specific date?

Tags: c#, winforms, datepicker

How can I set a DateTimePicker control to a specific date (yesterday's date) in C# .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Just need to set the value property in a convenient place (such as `InitializeComponent()`):

```
    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: Form_Load event is the most suitable place to set specific date to the datetimepicker control

Answer (score 25):

If you want to set a date, DateTimePicker.Value is a DateTime object.

```
DateTimePicker.Value = new DateTime(2012,05,28);
```

This is the constructor of DateTime:

```
new DateTime(int year,int month,int date);
```

My Visual is 2012

Comment: This is the most useful answer if anyone navigated here to get an answer to the actual title

Answer (score 9):

You can set the "value" property

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today;
```

Answer (score 4):

Can't figure out why, but in some circumstances if you have bound DataTimePicker and BindingSource contol is postioned to a new record, setting to Value property doesn't affect to bound field, so when you try to commit changes via EndEdit() method of BindingSource, you receive Null value doesn't allowed error.
I managed this problem setting direct DataRow field.

Answer (score 2):

This oughta do it.

```
DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Value` property.

```
MyDateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
```

`DateTime.Today` holds today's date, from which you can subtract 1 day (add -1 days) to become yesterday.

`DateTime.Now`, on the other hand, contains time information as well. `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)` will return this time one day ago.

Answer (score 1):

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. The question asked *How can I set a DateTimePicker control to a specific date **(yesterday's date)***

Answer (score 1):

Also, we can assign the Value to the Control in Designer Class (i.e. FormName.Designer.cs).

```
DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

This way you always get Current Date...

Answer (score 1):

FYI: If you are setting the value, and not seeing anything - you might check to see if you have a 'CustomFormat' set - I just hit this and it was set to ' ' for the 1/1/1900 value (our 'not set' value) and set to MM/dd/yyyy if not.

Comment: yes, and if you, as I did, set the Text property to the empty string (in my case as a part of a generel controls reset function), it will not allow you update the date programmatically.