# Saving date with datetimepicker through dropdown menu or manualy selecting a date

Tags: c#

I'm creating a datetimepicker which can save through a dropdown menu (with options like +14 days) and it also should save by manualy selecting a date in the datetimepicker.

[example of the dropdown](http://s1.postimg.org/h6tlcjmob/kalender.png)

14 dagen na is dutch for 14 days later so basicly that part works (also in the db).

But now the other part, i'm trying to make it that you can overwrite the dropdown by simpily selecting a date in the datetimepicker but I'm clueless how to.

This is my code for that part it basicly calculates the time between the "start" and the "end" date and will fill in the datetimepicker afterwords.

```
 private void cbBetalingsConditie_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        Locatie_reservering lr = new Locatie_reservering();
        string ResDatum = lr.getFirstDate(reservering.getID());
        DateTime FactuurDatum = betalingsConditie.BerekenFactuurdatum(cbBetalingsConditie.SelectedValue.ToString(), ResDatum);
        DateTime BetaalDatum = betalingsConditie.BerekenBetaaldatum(cbBetalingsConditie.SelectedValue.ToString(), FactuurDatum, ResDatum);
        dateTimePicker1.Value = BetaalDatum;
}
```

Comment: Is this a WinForm application or an aspx website?

Comment: Winform application sorry didn't mention

Comment: Okay then see my answer below

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set a DateTimePicker control to a specific date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541225/how-can-i-set-a-datetimepicker-control-to-a-specific-date)

Comment: @Pseudonym i cant really get the onclick function to work. Do u have a link to a good explanation or could u help me?

Comment: here yah go: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Pseudonym onclick cant be used in datetimepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is WinForms (if not let me know and I will update) MSDN shows you have to set the DateTimePicker.Value property in code [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public MyClass()
{

   YourDateTimePickerId.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
   MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
}
```

So what this code lets you do is to manually set the Value of the DateTimePicker, which means you can set up a button click to call a function to manually set the date.

Comment: Sure thing! If you consider this answering your question feel free to accept it when you can (I know time limits apply)