# How to setup DateTimePicker to load current system date by default?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

My **`DateTimePicker`** control won't load current system date by default in ***Visual Studio 2010***, is that a bug in **`DateTimePicker`** or need some setup or additional coding to load current system date in windows form application?

Comment: this is not that difficult I really can't believe that you are having this difficult of a time assigning `DateTime.Now.ToString()` to the DateTimePicker control.. what have you tried can you show us in code how you are doing this.. `dateTimePicker1.Value.Date = DateTime.Now.ToString()`

Comment: No, it's not a bug. Post your code. This question has already been answered many times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541225/how-can-i-set-a-datetimepicker-control-to-a-specific-date

Comment: dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now and `Google is an amazing tool if used properly

Comment: t shows current date by default. If you don't see the current date it's because you probably set the `Value` at design time and the designer serializes and shows that value when you show the form. You can right click on `Value` property in property grid and choose Reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows current date by default.

The default behaviour of `DateTimePicker` is showing current date if you don't set `Value` property at design time.

So if you don't see the current date it's because you probably set the `Value` at design time and the designer serializes and shows that value when you show the form.

You can right click on `Value` property in property grid and choose `Reset`.

Also you can simply set the value using `dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;` in `Load` event of your form.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback:)

Comment: Thanks to you brother for helping newbies in programming :)

Answer (score 1):

It couldn't be simpler:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
}
```