# Set date picker controls value behind 2 days

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0

Currently the date picker control value by default set to current date. I want to set it to two days before the current date. I am using form controls. I tried the below code,

```
DatePicker cntrl = new DatePicker();
cntrl.Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2);
this.Controls.Add(cntrl);

<Control>
        <ControlType>DatePicker</ControlType>
        <Left>20</Left>
        <Top>325</Top>
        <Width>150</Width>
        <Name>DatePickerPackDate</Name>
        <DataField>HarvestDate</DataField>
        <MaxDateToday>false</MaxDateToday>
        <DefaultToday>true</DefaultToday>
        <StartWithBlank>false</StartWithBlank>
    </Control>
```

the above code is not working, it always shows the current date in date picker control.

I want to show 11/16/2015 if today is 11/18/2015. How to forcefully over right the current date to two days back in date picker.

Thanks

Comment: is this windows form?

Comment: that code should work. Are you sure you aren't setting the value of that control at a later point in time? Or that you are watching a different control in the UI? A heavily upvoted answer with, basically, this code was given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/541248/937093) to a similiar question.

Comment: Do you mean DateTimePicker? I'm not seeing this UI element. Ok, I see it's a new element in .NET 4.0. You need to set the SelectedDate property to the DateTime value, not the Value property.

Comment: @Sajeetharan It is windows form. I updated the controls code.

Comment: @Royal why is there XAML code in your code sample if you are using Windows Forms?

Comment: @SteffenWinkler I am placing all the control in XML file, creating the UI at run time. This is because a non technical support guy will also create a textbox control and that values are also included in label printing with out any new source code in production.

Comment: @Royal in that case ChrisF's answer would be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the control to default to today:

```
<DefaultToday>true</DefaultToday>
```

Remove this line or set the property to `false`.

Comment: SelectedDate property is not found for DatePicker control. Any other way to do this

Answer (score 0):

If this is a DatePicker element you need to set the SelectedDate property:

```
 DatePicker cntrl = new DatePicker();
    cntrl.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2);
    this.Controls.Add(cntrl);
```

If this is a DateTimePicker then you can use the Value property:

```
 DateTimePicker cntrl = new DateTimePicker();
    cntrl.Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2);
    this.Controls.Add(cntrl);
```

Comment: SelectedDate property is not found for DatePicker control. I tried the 2nd option and the datepicker is not visible now. Any idea how to show datepicker using DateTimePicker control.

Comment: cntrl.Visible = True but the control should be defaulted to visible.